# Php mysql dynamic array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need to script and appends it overwrites! Main key is $EventID

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM events ");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$EventID = $row['EventID'];

$PresentationMethod = $row['PresentationMethod'];

$TimeStart = $row['TimeStart'];

$DateStart = $row['DateStart'];

$A[$EventID][$Language][$PresentationMethod][$TimeStart] = array($DateStart);

}
```

I have this :

```
Array ( 
  [301384] => Array (
    [ENG] => Array (
      [2D] => Array (
        [10:20:00] => Array (
           [0] => 2014-09-26 
        ) 
        [17:30:00] => Array (
           [0] => 2014-09-20 
        )
      ) 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

NEED:

```
Array ( 
  [301384] => Array (
    [ENG] => Array (
      [2D] => Array (
        [10:20:00] => Array (
          [0] => 2014-09-26,
          [1] => 2014-09-27,
          [1] => 2014-09-28 
        ) 
        [17:30:00] => Array (
          [0] => 2014-09-20,
          [1] => 2014-09-22 
        ), 
      [3D] => Array (
        [10:30:00] => Array (
          [0] => 2014-09-27,
          [1] => 2014-09-28,
          [1] => 2014-09-29 
        ) 
        [17:67:00] => Array (
          [0] => 2014-09-21, 
          [1] => 2014-09-23 
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your php code for assigning datestart like this instead of creating a array every time

```
$A[$EventID][$Language][$PresentationMethod][$TimeStart][] = $DateStart;
```